# Symfony2 Form request is empty

Tags: symfony

I use symfony2 for my website, where I have a register form. On my local  local environment everything works fine, but when I update it on a live server, when I tied to create a new user, the request is empty.

here is my code:

```
<form role="form" action="{{ path('register_response') }}" method="post" {{  form_enctype(form) }}>

  <div class="form-group  {{ firstNameError }}">
    {{ form_label(form.first_name, first_name) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.first_name, { 'attr': { 'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder' : first_name} }) }}
    {{ form_errors(form.first_name) }}
  </div>

  <div class="form-group   {{ lastNameError }}">
    {{ form_label(form.last_name, last_name) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.last_name, { 'attr': { 'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder' : last_name} }) }}
    {{ form_errors(form.last_name) }}
  </div>

  <div class="form-group   {{ emailError }}">
    {{ form_label(form.email, email_address) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.email, { 'attr': { 'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder' : 'email@example.com'} }) }}
    {{ form_errors(form.email) }}
  </div>

  <div class="form-group   {{ passError }}">
    {{ form_label(form.password, password) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.password, { 'attr': { 'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder' : password} }) }}
    {{ form_errors(form.password) }}
  </div>

  <div class="form-group   {{ repeatPassError }}">
    {{ form_label(form.repeat_password, repeat_password) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.repeat_password, { 'attr': { 'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder' : repeat_password} }) }}
    {{ form_errors(form.repeat_password) }}
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    {{ form_label(form.country, country) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.country, { 'attr': { 'class': 'form-control'} }) }}
    {{ form_errors(form.country) }}
  </div>

  <div class="form-group   {{ cityError }}">
    {{ form_label(form.city, city) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.city, { 'attr': { 'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder' : city} }) }}
    {{ form_errors(form.city) }}
  </div>

  <div class="form-group   {{ zipError }}">
    {{ form_label(form.zip_code, zip_code) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.zip_code, { 'attr': { 'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder' : zip_code} }) }}
    {{ form_errors(form.zip_code) }}
  </div>

  <div class="form-group   {{ addressError }}">
    {{ form_label(form.address, address) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.address, { 'attr': { 'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder' : address} }) }}
    {{ form_errors(form.address) }}
  </div>

        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">{{ register }}</button>
 </form>
```

Here is a image with request from server

[image]

And here is a image with request from my local environment :

[image]

Comment: Can you make a screenshot of the request shown in your browser's development tools?

Comment: Why are you using {% block %}?

Comment: I removed the block and I have the same problem

Comment: did you clear the cache on the live server?  Any changes that are made while in `prod` mode require you to clear your cache.

Comment: And how can I clear the cache from the server. I don't have directly access to server.